# passing azure container registry credential while creating azure webapp for multi container

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I am creating azure webapp (multi container app) using CLI. My docker images are in azure container registry(ACR). how do i pass my registry credentials to it or pass some flag that it recognise that images need to be pulled from ACR.

here is my command running from my linux machine (logged in with az login)

```
az webapp create --resource-group RishiCTS --plan rishi-kpi --name rishi-models --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose-models.yml
```

update: In azure portal I can pass docker-compose and select image source as ACR, but this start only first service from docker-compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the image in the YAML like this:

```
image: myregistry.azurecr.io/image:tag
```

Then the Web App will pull the image from your Container Registry. You can take a look at the [example for multiple containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app). And then you need to add the credential of the ACR with the environment variables:

- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME - The username for the ACR server.
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL - The full URL to the ACR server. (For
  example, https://my-server.azurecr.io.)
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD - The password for the ACR server.

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#if-youre-using-azure-container-registry-you-need-to-set-some-app-settingsapplies-to-web-app-for-containers).

Comment: Yes i have tried with that, but as i said in update it only server first container

Comment: @HiteshGhuge All the images in the docker-compose need to pull from the same registry. So if one image you want to pull from the ACR, you need to push all the images to ACR and then pull them from it.

Comment: Yes all the images are from the ACR only

Comment: @HiteshGhuge What do you mean only the first service? It does not work for other images?

Comment: Yes.... If I have 4 services in docker-compose it only stats first service out of it. Ihave doubt on ports, but I didn't found much about port on net

Comment: @HiteshGhuge Actually, the Azure Web App only can expose one port to outside, and it must be one of 80 and 443. So if you want to expose multiple ports, then it's impossible.

Comment: Ohk... So is there any alternative for listening multiple ports.

Comment: @HiteshGhuge For Azure Web App, only one port you can expose to outside, but you can expose multiple ports between containers, not outside. There is no way to expose multiple ports outside. And if you want to expose multiple ports to the outside, you can use the ACI.

Comment: @HiteshGhuge And if it solves your problem, please accept it.